# Can't center a parent inline-block DIV with a child Inline-block DIV inside

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs inside a parent div and they are displayed inline. The problem is that one of the 2 DIVS also needs to be displayed inline which prevents me from centering them both. Basically I need inline buttons on the left and text that is summing up the information of the page on the right. The text and the buttons must be centered.  https://jsfiddle.net/yLnt56ew/1/

```css
.all_parent {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.Box_button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  margin: 15px 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Box_button:hover {
  background-color: #1e75ff;
}

.box_text {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 95px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Box_parent {
  max-width: 700px;
}

#project_line {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.project_text {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 350px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="all_parent">

  <div class="Box_parent" id="project_line">
    <a>
      <div class="Box_button">
        <div class="box_text"> TEST </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="Box_button">
        <div class="box_text"> TEST </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="Box_button">
        <div class="box_text"> TEST </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="Box_button">
        <div class="box_text"> TEST </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="Box_button">
        <div class="box_text"> TEST </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a>
      <div class="Box_button">
        <div class="box_text"> TEST </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="project_line" class="project_text">
    <h1>TEST </h1>
    <a> TEST</br> random text and some more random text! random text and some more random text! random text and some more random text! </br></br> TEST </br> random text and some more random text! </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be a little bit more precise: you want to center both buttons and text vertically or horizontally? What should they be in the center of: the window or their common parent?

Please check your markup and css - you use `id="project_line"` twice, which is invalid.

Comment: I need all the stuff centered horizontally. And I don't see a "valid" way to display 2 DIVS inline without using `id="project_line"` for each DIV.

Comment: try flexbox....

Comment: @ValioRaltchev as @abney317 mentions in the answer below, a class called `all_parent` would be the way to go. IDs must be unique, classes can be applied to multiple elements. [Read more here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"all_parent" is an ID not a class.

Change `.all_parent` to `#all_parent` in your CSS and the centering works.

Also you should double check your markup because you're leaving out closing tags for elements.

Comment: Really stupid mistake from my side. I was looking for hours and it seems the eye was lying me all the time. Thank you!